# EF Core в MVC, many to many. Почему не отображается свойство модели?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Сделал модели по примеру, описанному на [Metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php). Но не отображается информация о роли:
[image: вывод User.UserRoles]

Хотя при дебаге вроде все норм:

[image: users[0].UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserId = users[0].Id, RoleId = roles[0].Id });]

Пробовал указать вручную:

```
users[0].UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserId = users[0].Id, RoleId = roles[0].Id, Role = roles[0], User = users[0] });
```

но безрезультатно.

В гугле решение проблемы не нашел. Сам в EF Core и ASP.NET новичок, идей для решения нет.
Благодарен буду, если кто сможет помочь или направить на решение.

**Модели:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**Метод в контроллере:**

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            User user = await db.Users.Include(a => a.UserAccounts).
                Include(b => b.UserRoles).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
            if (user != null)
                return View(user);
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

**Класс инициализатор:**

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (context.Users.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var users = new User[]
        {
            new User{ Name = "Дмитрий" },
            new User{ Name = "Валерия" },
            new User{ Name = "Александр" },
        };

        foreach (var u in users)
        {
            context.Users.Add(u);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();


        var roles = new Role[]
        {
            new Role { Name = "User" },
            new Role { Name = "Admin" }
        };

        foreach (var r in roles)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(r);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

        users[0].UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { UserId = users[0].Id, RoleId = roles[0].Id });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Класс контекст:**

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
    }
}
```

**Вывод в** *Details.cshtml* **:**

```
<dd class="col-sm-10">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Id роли</th>
                <th>Роль</th>
                <th>Id user</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model.UserRoles)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </dd>
```

Comment: А в бд данные правильно записались?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял - ваша проблема заключается в том что на View (Details.cshtml) в модели User.Role = null? Если да, то судя по коду контроллера, вы используете eagerLoad  (`Include()`) только для таблицы связи, и не используете его для самой таблицы роли. Т.е. это эквивалентно одному `User Join User2Roles`. А вы видимо хотите `User Join User2Roles Join Roles`. Попробуйте добавить `ThenIclude` для Roles в коде контроллера:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        User user = await db.Users.Include(a => a.UserAccounts)
            .Include(b => b.UserRoles)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
        if (user != null)
            return View(user);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, помогло. Но вместо `ThenInclude(x => x.UserRoles.Role)` просто `ThenInclude(x => x.Role)`

Comment: @Srul1k всегда пожалуйста. `x.Role` - вы правы